# How to convert query builder to eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have been trying to figure out how to implement a matching system but have become stuck.
I've managed to build a query within a controller which does exactly the same thing as I want it to do, but I would like to convert it to an Eloquent Model since images are broken and also can access some functions inside my Model.

Here's the query builder within the controller that I wish to convert (if it's possible at all)- I am checking if users have both "liked" each other (similar to Tinder):

```
class MatchedEmployersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $matches = DB::table('applicant_likes')
        ->join('employers', 'employers.id', '=', 'applicant_likes.liked_employer_id')
        ->whereExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('employer_likes')
                ->whereRaw('employer_likes.employer_id = applicant_likes.liked_employer_id');
        })
        ->get();

        return view('applicant.employers.matched', compact('matches'));
    }
}
```

Here's the Applicant model where below I extracted the logic into a usable Traits

```
App\Models\Applicant

class Applicant extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, LikeableEmployer, MatchableEmployer;

    //

    public function getAvatarAttribute($value)
    {
        return asset($value ?: '/images/default-avatar.jpeg');
    }
}
```

```
App\Trais\LikeableEmployer

trait LikeableEmployer
{
    public function likeEmployer(Employer $employer)
    {
        return $this->likedEmployers()->save($employer);
    }

    public function unlikeEmployer(Employer $employer)
    {
        return $this->likedEmployers()->detach($employer);
    }

    public function toggleLikeEmployer(Employer $employer)
    {
        if ($this->likingEmployer($employer)) {
            return $this->unlikeEmployer($employer);
        }
        return $this->likeEmployer($employer);
    }

    public function likingEmployer(Employer $employer)
    {
        return $this->likedEmployers()->where('liked_employer_id', $employer->id)->exists();
    }

    public function likedEmployers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Employer::class, 'applicant_likes', 'applicant_id', 'liked_employer_id');
    }
}
```

finally, here's where the matched logic should be placed

```
namespace App\Traits;

use App\Traits\LikeableApplicant;
use App\Traits\LikeableEmployer;

trait MatchableEmployer
{
    use LikeableApplicant, LikeableEmployer;

    public function matchedEmployers()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table where you will store the matches. Let's take the following example.

`relationships` `table: id | from | to`, It's a match if we have a pair. Example:

```
id | from | to
1  | 1    | 2
2  | 2    | 1
```

Now create `Relationship` Model

```
class Relationship extends Model
{
    public static function getMatch($user_id)
    {
        return self::leftJoin('relationship reverse', 'relationship.to', '=', 'reverse.from')->where('relationship.from', 'reverse.to')->where('relationship.from', $user_id)->get();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call `User::getMatch('any_user_id');`

Comment: I didn't mention that I have already two authentication guards with two different Users tables and also using pivot tables where Everything is setup correctly, but i'll update my question, Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create the model for every table you used in this query, then add the following relationship.

## In ApplicantLike Model

```
public function employer(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Employer','liked_employer_id','id');
  }
```

## In Employer Model

```
 public function likes(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\EmployerLike','employer_id','id');
  }
```

## Final in your MatchedEmployersController

```
public function index()
{
    $matches = ApplicantLike::with('employer','employer.likes')
     ->has('employer')
     ->has('employer.likes')
     ->get();

     // dd($matches); // try with this first
    return view('applicant.employers.matched', compact('matches'));
}
```

## Try the above code, I converted your given code into ORM, but I think that you are implementing the wrong logic for what you need. If anything will not work fine just reply to me I will help you.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, i guess i have to update my question since I am using two guard authentication and also using pivot tables .